# Hash of my windows 11 iso file doesnt match with windows iso list

Tags: windows

My hash is:**C7C0E3EFF454BB23133AC9F59D8F7E74298C072F7ECB672CB61D271060996E17**.
Is this legitimate windows installer?

Comment: We need to have more information about the ISO. Without this information it’s impossible to and your question. My suggestion use the Media Creation Tool to download the ISO or install Windows 11

Comment: Name of the iso file is:Win11_22H2_English_x64v1.iso and hash is:0DF2F173D84D00743DC08ED824FBD174D972929BD84B87FE384ED950F5BDAB22.Is it allright?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a legitimate Windows 11 installer from Microsoft.

If your hash does not match the Microsoft List, then it is most likely (greater than 90%) not legitimate.

I would get another installer directly from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I did it from official microsoft site.However I did it trough microsoft 11 installation media.I then tried to manually download windows iso file from microsoft,my language is English(US) and this is the has code that I get:0DF2F173D84D00743DC08ED824FBD174D972929BD84B87FE384ED950F5BDAB22

Comment: @GreyCow if you used the media creator then it may not give the same hash as a proper ISO file downloaded from Microsoft.

Comment: Indeed,so as I said I did download iso file only after that,but I dont know where I can find a trustworthy source to check my hash.

Comment: Microsoft is always a trustworthy source of hashes to check files. So maybe your source redirected you (even if you were not aware)

Comment: @GreyCow - The Media Creation Tool doesn't create a 1:1 copy. In other words two copies of the ISO won't match, when downloaded from the MCT, if you downloaded it through the tool then it's legitmant.